# How to get Children width in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is an online sample https://codesandbox.io/s/jovial-resonance-5mjq0

```
const Parent = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: yellow;
  justify-content: space-between;
`;

const Children = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  background: tomato;
  height: 50px;
  flex: 0 0 10%;
`;

function App() {
  return (
    <Parent>
      <Children />
      <Children />
      <Children />
      <Children />
      <Children />
    </Parent>
  );
}
```

So regardless the window resizing. 
so pure javascript can be done like

```
document.querySelectorAll(CHILDREN).forEach(e=> {
e.clientWidth
})
```

but how to get `<Children />`'s width? I understand it may not common to play DOM in reactjs. But is there a react way to get width? Thanks

Comment: See refs. https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: Thanks. If there are many elements to play with, then need to create `Refs` for all of them..Not kinda efficient, but might be the only way?

Comment: Indeed (unless you can get away by measuring their bounding element).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `refs` to get DOM elements (after rendering). If you need the width of multiple elements either use several refs and some arithmetic, or use an enveloping parent.

```js
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.elementRef = React.createRef();
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    // get the BCR of your ref
    const bcr = this.elementRef.current.getBoundingClientRect()
    console.log({ width: bcr.width });
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div style={{ width: '234px' }}>
        <div ref={this.elementRef} style={{ width: '50%' }}>
          Hello, World!
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, if we know the `className` of children, can we just use `document.getElementsByClassName('ChildrenClassName')`? inside ` componentDidMount(){}`

Comment: You can do that (given that the classes are not mangled). Avoiding DOM manipulations and stuff if not neccesary is just a general rule of thumb, but sometimes you have to get your hands dirty.